# Spotify SDK mysteriously fails to play certain songs

Tags: android, spotify

I have been trying to create a music app built around the Spotify Android SDK.

For some reason, when certain songs are played, the Spotify player will behave as if everything is working fine, but no music will play. This only happens ≈90% of the time for a problem track. The other 10% of the time it will play fine.

From what I can tell, this issue only happens with short (<30s) tracks.

About the only difference between a successful play and an unsuccessful play is that `kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged` is only called if music actually plays.

There are no error messages, and `onSuccess()` is called even if it plays.

Both songs are available in my area.

Below is a simple test file I put together to test the issue without worrying about there being an issue with my code. Even (seemingly) eliminating any outside factors the issue persists. The call to `playUri(...)` is within `onLoggedIn()`.

```
public class ActivityHost extends ActivityPlayer implements Player.NotificationCallback, ConnectionStateCallback, Player.OperationCallback
{

public static final String CLIENT_ID = "ad5cd6a8c83843e19eb8cbf67663a3a3";
public static final String REDIRECT_URI = "auxparty-spotify://callback";

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 4321;

Player mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_host);

    AuthenticationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthenticationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID,
            AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN,
            REDIRECT_URI);
    builder.setScopes(new String[]{"streaming"});
    AuthenticationRequest request = builder.build();

    AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, request);

    initializeViews();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
        if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN)
        {
            String token = response.getAccessToken();

            Config playerConfig = new Config(getApplicationContext(), token, ActivityHost.CLIENT_ID);
            Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer)
                {
                    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Player initialized");
                    mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
                    mPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(ActivityHost.this);
                    mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(ActivityHost.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable)
                {
                    Log.e("auxparty-spotify", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoggedIn() {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "User logged in");

    //Player usually fails when this song is played
    mPlayer.playUri(ActivityHost.this, "spotify:track:008GDaR710wy4nlvXh7Lwm", 0, 0); 


    //Player succeeds when this song is played 
    mPlayer.playUri(ActivityHost.this, "spotify:track:077OhUjy58qkjscrXjW696", 0, 0); 
}

@Override
public void onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent)
{
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Playback event received: " + playerEvent.name());

    switch (playerEvent)
    {
        // Handle event type as necessary
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPlaybackError(com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Error error) {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Playback error received: " + error.name());
    switch (error) {
        // Handle error type as necessary
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoggedOut() {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "User logged out");
}

@Override
public void onLoginFailed(com.spotify.sdk.android.player.Error error) {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Login failed");
}

@Override
public void onTemporaryError() {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Temporary error occurred");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionMessage(String message) {
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "Received connection message: " + message);
}

@Override
public void onError(Error error)
{
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onSuccess()
{
    Log.d("auxparty-spotify", "playback success");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Spotify.destroyPlayer(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Would share the logs of both cases ? i've been having a similar issue